# React app not building - can't find react chalk module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, npm-scripts, chalk

I have an app on a digital ocean droplet running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

I clone the repo into the droplet and install node 10 and build essentials.

Then when I do npm run build I get this:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/chalk'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myapp/scripts/build.js:19:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I tried to solve this by downgrading react-dev-utils with

```
npm i react-dev-utils@10.2.1
```

But then I get these errors:

```
==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x1ea12c15be1d]
Security context: 0x1947c8e9e6c1 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */ [0x30c82ea822c1] [/myapp/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:~342] [pc=0x1ea12d633728](this=0x0a79fda8d461 <JSGlobal Object>,chunk=0x1170cdcc1899 <String[6]: target>,original=0x26e0d9395289 <Object map = 0x1d7289a35fd1>)
    2: SourceNode_walk [0x3581cd4fb1f1] [/myapp/node_modules/webpack-sourc...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x8fb090 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x8fb0dc  [node]
 3: 0xb033ae v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb035e4 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xef7642  [node]
 6: 0xef7748 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [node]
 7: 0xf03822 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xf04154 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xf06dc1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xed0244 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [node]
11: 0x117031e v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
12: 0x1ea12c15be1d
Aborted (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! myapp@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-08-11T13_15_27_180Z-debug.log
```

The log file is:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v10.22.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~prebuild: myapp@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: myapp@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/myapp/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbi$
9 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: CWD: /myapp
10 silly lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'node scripts/build.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 134  signal: null
12 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: myapp@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 134
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid myapp@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /myapp
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-66-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.22.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 134
22 error myapp@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
22 error Exit status 134
23 error Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 134, true ]
```